# Should I use a protocol or category with associative objects to give my child view controllers properties?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Im building a custom view controller container and im figuring out which to use to give my children view controllers properties, similarly like UINavigationController grabs a view ontroller's title property, and left and right bar button item. What are the pros and cons of each? Note, i have seen the category method used more such as in te excellent View Deck Controller (https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) and a bunch of other components

**EDIT**
viewDeck and other controllers use associative objects in conjunction with the category to pull this off.

Comment: Are you sure ViewDeck is using a category for that? Maybe it is an class extension? Where exactly did you see that?

Comment: Im sorry, it uses associative objects to actually set it. Check out this code and search for AssociatedObject https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/blob/05370cf710a55e1f5912febcc5464c327361b4dc/ViewDeck/IIViewDeckController.m

Comment: Associative objects aren't properties. IMHO using them is a strong indication that it is time to do proper subclassing.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend not using a category: there are a number of XCode/LLVM compiler issues with adding libraries/frameworks that use categories to XCode projects (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html). Protocols work cleanly for this sort of thing, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that I would use either. I think I would create a base view controller class with the properties, and then have all your child view controllers inherit from this class. Categories can contain methods but not storage, so no ivars or properties (that have a backing ivar).

Comment: sorry, please see my comment to ikini viking above